# Show/Hide/Disable A 'Remove' Button On A NG-Grid

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs application which has a `data-ng-grid`. This table automatically displays 1 row by default and the last column displays a 'Remove' button but as this table has to have 1 or more entries in it I want to remove/disable this button when only one row is present in it.

I have tried adding `ng-if="propertyIncomeGrid.count > 1"` but when I click my add button it doesn't display on any row.

Please note that the user can delete any row so the button needs to be displayed as soon as the table row are `> 1` and removed/disabled when `<= 1`.

**Code**

```
$scope.propertyIncomeGrid = {
     data: 'propertyIncomeData',
     enableColumnReordering: false,
     rowHeight: 40,
     multiSelect: false,
     showColumnMenu: false,
     showFooter: false,
     enableColumnResize: true,
     filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
     selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
     enablePaging: false,
     plugins: [gridLayoutPlugin],         
     columnDefs:
     [
          { field: 'PropertyTransactionType', displayName: 'Income type', width: '18%', enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate: incomeDropdownTemplate },
          { field: 'leaseId', displayName: 'Property ID and lease name', width: '30%', enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate: leaseDropdownTemplate },
          { field: 'propertyId', displayName: 'propertyId', width: '0', editableCellTemplate: '' },
          { field: 'netAmount', displayName: 'Net (£)', width: '14%', cellTemplate: AmountCellTemplate },
          { field: 'vatAmount', displayName: 'VAT (£)', width: '14%', cellTemplate: AmountCellTemplate },
          { field: 'GROSSAmount', displayName: 'Gross (£)', width: '14%', cellTemplate: AmountCellTemplate },
          {
               field: 'removeBtn', displayName: 'Actions',
               enableCellEdit: false,
               cellTemplate: '<button class="btn btn-warning ng-if="propertyIncomeGrid.count > 1"  ng-click="propertyIncomeRemoveRow(row.entity)" style="margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">Remove</button>',
               width: '10%'
          },
     ]
};
```

I have tried debugging and it only hits when my modal loads and comes back as `undefined`.

Comment: can you add a fiddle pls

Comment: @Jax Thanks for the reply but I have managed to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the below to my button and works like magic:

`ng-disabled="propertyIncomeData != undefined && propertyIncomeData.length < 2"`

**Full button code**

```
cellTemplate: '<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="propertyIncomeData != undefined && propertyIncomeData.length < 2" ng-click="propertyIncomeRemoveRow(row.entity)" style="margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">Remove</button>',
```